# Zip support in Apache Spark

Tags: compression, zip, apache-spark

I have read about *Spark*'s support for *gzip*-kind input files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302385/gzip-support-in-spark), and I wonder if the same support exists for different kind of compressed files, such as *.zip* files. So far I have tried computing a file compressed under a *zip* file, but *Spark* seems unable to read its contents successfully.

I have taken a look to *Hadoop*'s `newAPIHadoopFile` and `newAPIHadoopRDD`, but so far I have not been able to get anything working.

In addition, *Spark* supports creating a partition for every file under a specified folder, like in the example below:

```
SparkConf SpkCnf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkApp")
                                  .setMaster("local[4]");

JavaSparkContext Ctx = new JavaSparkContext(SpkCnf);

JavaRDD<String> FirstRDD = Ctx.textFile("C:\input\).cache();
```

Where `C:\input\` points to a directory with multiple files.

In the case computing *zipped* files would be possible, would it also be possible to pack every file under a single compressed file and follow the same pattern of *one partition per file*?

Answer (score 11):

## Spark default support compressed files

According to [Spark Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#external-datasets)

> All of Spark’s file-based input methods, including textFile, support running on directories, compressed files, and wildcards as well. For example, you can use textFile("/my/directory"), textFile("/my/directory/*.txt"), and textFile("/my/directory/*.gz").

This could be expanded by providing information about what compression formats are supported by Hadoop, which basically can be checked by finding all classes extending `CompressionCodec` ([docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/CompressionCodec.html))

```
name    | ext      | codec class
-------------------------------------------------------------
bzip2   | .bz2     | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec 
default | .deflate | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec 
deflate | .deflate | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec 
gzip    | .gz      | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec 
lz4     | .lz4     | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec 
snappy  | .snappy  | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
```

*Source : [List the available hadoop codecs](https://gist.github.com/chetan/6524829)*

So the above formats and much more possibilities could be achieved simply by calling:

```
sc.readFile(path)
```

## Reading zip files in Spark

Unfortunately, `zip` is not on the supported list by default.

I have found a great article: [Hadoop: Processing ZIP files in Map/Reduce](http://cutler.io/2012/07/hadoop-processing-zip-files-in-mapreduce/) and some answers ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28636651/1549135)) explaining how to use imported `ZipFileInputFormat` together with `sc.newAPIHadoopFile` API. But this **did not work for me**.

## My solution

Without any external dependencies, you can load your file with `sc.binaryFiles` and later on decompress the `PortableDataStream` reading the content. This is the approach I have chosen.

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

implicit class ZipSparkContext(val sc: SparkContext) extends AnyVal {

    def readFile(path: String,
                 minPartitions: Int = sc.defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String] = {

      if (path.endsWith(".zip")) {
        sc.binaryFiles(path, minPartitions)
          .flatMap { case (name: String, content: PortableDataStream) =>
            val zis = new ZipInputStream(content.open)
            // this solution works only for single file in the zip
            val entry = zis.getNextEntry
            val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis))
            Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)
          }
      } else {
        sc.textFile(path, minPartitions)
      }
    }
  }
```

using this implicit class, you need to import it and call the `readFile` 
method on `SparkContext`:

```
import com.github.atais.spark.Implicits.ZipSparkContext
sc.readFile(path)
```

And the implicit class will load your `zip` file properly and return `RDD[String]` like it used to.

**Note: This only works for single file in the zip archive!**
*For multiple files in your zip support, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958458/1549135*

Comment: You are not closing the connections.

Comment: Any idea of approach with directory containing multiple zip files (partitions)?

Comment: This works great with readFile, how about datasource api such as CSV reader (csv => dataframe) ?

Answer (score 7):

Since Apache Spark uses Hadoop Input formats we can look at the hadoop documentation on how to process zip files and see if there is something that works.

[This site](http://cotdp.com/2012/07/hadoop-processing-zip-files-in-mapreduce/) gives us an idea of how to use this (namely we can use the ZipFileInputFormat). That being said, since zip files are not split-table (see [this](https://github.com/cotdp/com-cotdp-hadoop/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cotdp/hadoop/ZipFileInputFormat.java)) your request to have a single compressed file isn't really well supported. Instead, if possible, it would be better to have a directory containing many separate zip files.

This question is similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569788/how-to-open-stream-zip-files-through-spark), however it adds an additional question of if it would be possible to have a single zip file (which, since it isn't a split-table format isn't a good idea).

Answer (score 2):

You can use sc.binaryFiles to read Zip as binary file

```
val rdd = sc.binaryFiles(path).flatMap { 
    case (name: String, content: PortableDataStream) => new ZipInputStream(content.open) 
}  //=> RDD[ZipInputStream]
```

And then you can map the ZipInputStream to list of lines:

```
val zis = rdd.first
val entry = zis.getNextEntry
val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"))
val res = Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null).toList
```

But the problem remains that the zip file is not splittable.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I tried this but getting error. can u please help?

val zipFileRDD = sc.binaryFiles(zipFile).flatMap { case (name: String, content: PortableDataStream)
=> new ZipInputStream(content.open) }
> 
> <console>:95: error: type mismatch;
>  found   : java.util.zip.ZipInputStream
>  required: TraversableOnce[?]
>          val zipFileRDD = sc.binaryFiles(zipFile).flatMap { case (name, content) =>
new ZipInputStream(content.open) }

Answer (score 2):

You can use sc.binaryFiles to open the zip file in binary format, then unzip it into the text format. Unfortunately, the zip file is not split-able.. So you need to wait for the decompression, then maybe call shuffle to balance the data in each partition.

Here is an example in Python. More info is in http://gregwiki.duckdns.org/index.php/2016/04/11/read-zip-file-in-spark/

```
 file_RDD = sc.binaryFiles( HDFS_path + data_path )

 def Zip_open( binary_stream_string ) : # New version, treat a stream as zipped file
     try :
         pseudo_file = io.BytesIO( binary_stream_string )
         zf = zipfile.ZipFile( pseudo_file )
         return zf
     except :
         return None

 def read_zip_lines(zipfile_object) :
     file_iter = zipfile_object.open('diff.txt')
     data =  file_iter.readlines() 
     return data

 My_RDD = file_RDD.map(lambda kv: (kv[0], Zip_open(kv[1])))
```

Comment: What is zipfile_object and how does one call it up and display the contents? Please provide example. I have one csv .zip file and the path is know?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example which searches a directory for .zip files and create an RDD using a custom FileInputFormat called `ZipFileInputFormat` and the newAPIHadoopFile API on the Spark Context. It then writes those files to an output directory.

```
allzip.foreach { x =>
  val zipFileRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    x.getPath.toString,
    classOf[ZipFileInputFormat],
    classOf[Text],
    classOf[BytesWritable], hadoopConf)

  zipFileRDD.foreach { y =>
    ProcessFile(y._1.toString, y._2)
  }
```

https://github.com/alvinhenrick/apache-spark-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/zip/example/Unzip.scala

The ZipFileInputFormat used in the example can be found here: https://github.com/cotdp/com-cotdp-hadoop/tree/master/src/main/java/com/cotdp/hadoop