# "close" a Stream?

Tags: scala, io, stream

I am reading text from a java `BufferedReader` like this:

```
Stream.continually(reader.readLine).takeWhile { 
   case null => reader.close; false
   case _ => true
}
```

This works, but just seems a little clumsy to me. I wish there was something like `.whenDone` on `Stream`, so that I could tell it to close the reader after the whole thing is consumed, and then just do `.takeWhile(_ != null)`.

Is there some way to do that I don't know about? Or, perhaps, a better way to get a stream of lines from a java `Reader` (if it was an `InputStream`, I could just do `Source.fromInputStream` for example, but there does not seem to be an equivalent for `Reader` ... note, that this would only partially solve the problem though, because one might want to do the same thing with other "closable" objects - a `ResultSet` for example)?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `.whenDone` behaviour by appending another `Stream`.
This makes the code a bit more expressive and could also be used in other cases. It is something but I guess far from perfect.

```
def closeStream: Stream[Nothing] = {
  reader.close
  Stream.Empty
}

Stream.continually(reader.readLine).takeWhile(_ != null) #::: closeStream
```