# Closing stream at the end in Apache Spark results in java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stream, inputstream, apache-spark-2.0

I have been facing a problem of **reading a zip** files in **Apache Spark** some time ago. I have shared [my answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958458/1549135).

As @Programmer aptly noted I am not closing opened streams. I tried achieving it with a partial function in `takeWhile` ([inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35746539/1549135))

```
Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry)
  .takeWhile {
    case null => zis.close(); false
    case _ => true
  }
  .flatMap { _ =>
    val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis))
    Stream.continually(br.readLine())
      .takeWhile{
        case null => br.close(); false
        case _ => true
      }
  }
```

**But it does not work!**

While reading the zip files, I get this error now:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 20, localhost): java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(ZipInputStream.java:67)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:116)
```

And simply by leaving it open - it works OK.

So it seems like I am closing the stream and then try to read it again. But I do not know why and how to solve it.

Comment: Is it not because when you close `br` stream, you are closing `zis` all along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @alexandre-dupriez comment I have closed only the outer `Stream` and this helped...

```
Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry)
  .takeWhile {
    case null => zis.close(); false
    case _ => true
  }
  .flatMap { _ =>
    val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis))
    Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)
  }
```

Thus I will need a while to confirm if it works as it should.