# How to read contents of a CSV file inside zip file using spark (python)

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, zip, pyspark

I have multiple zip files containing two types of files(A.csv & B.csv)

/data/jan.zip --> contains A.csv & B.csv
/data/feb.zip --> contains A.csv & B.csv

I want to read the contents of all the A.csv files inside all the zip files using pyspark.

```
 textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://<HDFS loc>/data/*.zip")
```

Can someone tell me how to get the contents of A.csv files into an RDD?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080475/how-to-read-a-zip-containing-multiple-files-in-apache-spark

Comment: [Read whole text files from a compression in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36604145/1560062)

Comment: This link might help you https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score -1):

Here you want to read all csv files inside the zip files recursively.

```
val files = sc.CSVFiles("file://path/to/files/*.zip")
files.flatMap({case (name, content) =>
  unzip(content)
})

def unzip(content: String): List[String] = {
  ...
}
```